# Powershell -replace regex not working on connection strings

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm attempting to use the Powershell `-replace` command to update the data source in my config file. However, the `-replace` regex below will not remove the `$oldServer` value.

I've place a string directly in to the `$_.connectionString` variable in the loop and it saved properly, so I know that is not the issue. Seems to just be the regex.

```
    #environment variables
    $env = "DEV"                    
    $oldServer = "quasq10"          
    $newValue = "$env-AR-SQL.CORP.COM"

    $doc = [xml](Get-Content "D:\AMS\app.config")      
    $doc.configuration.connectionStrings.add|%{        
        $_.connectionString = $_.connectionString -replace $oldServer, $newValue;
    }
    $doc.Save($file.FullName)
```

**EDIT**

Per the comment below I added a `Write-host $_.connectionString` statement as the first line in the loop. Below is the console output

> metadata=res://*/MonetDb.csdl|res://*/MonetDb.ssdl|res://*/MonetDb.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=quasq10\sql08a;initial catalog=MyDB
>   ;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework"

Comment: Well that is a pretty basic statement you have there so to figure out why it isn't matching we would probably need a sample of what is actually in `$_.connectionString` within your foreach. I suggest sticking a `Write-Host $_.connectionString` in the foreach to get a sample of the values to be matched and perhaps post them here.

Comment: Was just thinking the same. Added the connection string value to the post.

Answer (score 1):

I just put this right into ISE, I copied your connection string into a variable and was able to do this replace as a one off.

```
$connectionString = 'metadata=res:///MonetDb.csdl|res:///MonetDb.ssdl|res://*/MonetDb.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=quasq10\sql08a;initial catalog=MyDB ;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework"'
$env = "DEV"
$oldServer = "quasq10"          
$newValue = "$env-AR-SQL.CORP.COM"

$connectionString -replace $oldServer, $newValue
```

> res:///MonetDb.csdl|res:///MonetDb.ssdl|res://*/MonetDb.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=DEV-AR-SQL.CORP.COM\sql08a;initial catalog=MyDB ;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework"

I think your foreach loop might not be getting the info you want, because it looks like your replace is fine.

```
$doc.configuration.connectionStrings.add
```

I haven't done much with XML, does the XML data type have an ADD member function? You aren't really adding anything, right?

As a test, what do you get from this:

```
$doc.configuration.connectionStrings | % {        
    $_.connectionString -replace $oldServer, $newValue;
}
```

Run that against a dummy file and see what happens.

For a sanity check on the replace operator:

```
$string = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"
$oldColor = "brown"
$newColor = "orange"

$string -replace $oldColor, $newColor
```

To avoid digging through comments, this method worked

```
$string.Replace($oldColor,$newColor)
```

Comment: Interesting - so if I copy/paste the variables/regex from the top of your post into ISE I do not get the same results. The `$oldServer` value does not get replaced. Any idea why that would be? Haven't touched the code at all, just did a copy/paste.

Comment: Also if I set a breakpoint inside the `foreach` you have in your post, I see that the `-replace` line is hit, however again the regex fails to replace the old value.

Comment: What PowerShell version are you using? I'm using v4, though I'm not sure that would make a difference.

Comment: Using `$PSVersionTable` it looks like I'm on PSVersion 4.0 too.

Comment: Odd, just for sanity's sake I copied that back into ISE from my post here, and the -Replace still works as expected. Do you get any errors or warnings when doing the replace?

Comment: Literally nothing. Just passes over the final line no problem. Going to have a coworker run the same code and see what happens. In the meantime are there any modules you need to import to make this work?

Comment: There shouldn't be. How bout this for a test, set a variable to an arbitrary string... like, "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog", and then do a replace with brown to blue or something like that. That will verify if the replace operator is working correctly.

Comment: So... that didn't work either. After the regex is run the `$connectionString` variable still reads "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog". Brown wasn't replaced with blue. Any idea what that means?

Comment: ^Did another copy/paste directly from your post for the color test.

Comment: Truly I don't. Unless you need to use an alternate syntax, such as: $string.Replace($oldColor,$newColor)

Comment: Ok, so this syntax works. This places the correct string/replacement text in the `$string` variable: `$string = $connectionString.Replace($oldServer, $newValue)`